# How do I write a python opencv script for replacing a low quality video with a high quality video such that the audio syncs with new video?

Tags: python, opencv, audio, video

I have many hundreds of videos in two versions. One version is low quality video with a desired audio. The other version has high quality video but undesired audio. I would like to combine the HQ video of one with the desired audio of another by writing an openCV python script to automate this whole thing. How do I do this.

Comment: This does not sound like a job for a computer vision library.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably be better off doing this with [*ffmpeg*](http://ffmpeg.org).
I can't test the command myself now, but this should work:

```
ffmpeg -i video_hiqal.mp4 -i video_lowqal.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 output.mp4
```

Basically, *ffmpeg* will receive both video streams in input and, thanks to the `map` option, it'll use video from the first stream and audio from the second stream.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might want to consider the idea of ripping the audio off the clearer sounding video and attaching it to the one which has better visual quality and in that case, these links to will help you get the direct methods:

[Combining an audio file with video file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219049/combining-an-audio-file-with-video-file-in-python)

[Python extract wav from video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741116/python-extract-wav-from-video-file)