# Python- How can I copy sound from one file and paste it into other?

Tags: python, file, audio

I am working on a video editing project which edits the original video and creates a new file I got stuck becuse there is no sound in the new file which the software creates. So I want to copy the sound from the original file and paste it into the new file **(I have video in the new file, but the video file doesn't have any sound - I want to get sound from the original file and use this sound in my new file)**

Any ideas?

Here is my video editing script:

```
import io, re, requests
from PIL import  Image, ImageOps, ImageEnhance, ImageChops
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('original.mp4')

fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))
   
size = (frame_width, frame_height)
result = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'), fps,size)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    
   #editing part

    result.write(edited_frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can extract the sound from the video file and then "pasting" it into the silent mp4 file using moviepy (didn't test this, based only on reading)

```
video = mp.VideoFileClip(r"sample.mp4")
video.audio.write_audiofile(r"extracted_sound.mp3")
```

and then paste the sound:

```
import moviepy.editor as mpe
my_clip = mpe.VideoFileClip('output_video.mp4')
audio_background = mpe.AudioFileClip('extracted_sound.mp3')
final_audio = mpe.CompositeAudioClip([my_clip.audio, audio_background])
final_clip = my_clip.set_audio(final_audio)
```

====

based on:

https://dev.to/itsaditya/extracting-audio-from-video-clips-using-python-9d8

[Video editing with python : adding a background music to a video with sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48728145/video-editing-with-python-adding-a-background-music-to-a-video-with-sound)

Comment: Great. Glad to help. Good luck!