# How can I download videos from reddit using praw

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, praw

So I want to download videos from reddit, I've seen projects on github but I'm very new to python and don't know how it works, if someone could explain I'd appreciate it, I found this [project](https://pypi.org/project/redvid/) It works but it seperates audio and video and I want it all in one, I think you can combine those using ffmpeg but I don't know how that works either, also how do I configure some of this stuff like where the videos save and quality, here's my code.

```
from redvid import Downloader
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id = "a", client_secret = "b", user_agent = "c")

subreddit = reddit.subreddit("learnpython")
hot = subreddit.hot(limit=5)

downloader = Downloader(max_q=True)

for submission in hot:
    downloader.url = submission.url
    reddit.download()
```

Comment: Does this thread answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219049/combining-an-audio-file-with-video-file-in-python

Comment: Thank you, but how could I change the place where ffmpeg downloads are saved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a very easy to use library that installs reddit videos with sound just install [RedDownloader](https://pypi.org/project/RedDownloader/) by:

```
pip install RedDownloader
```

use it with:

```
from RedDownloader import RedDownloader

file = RedDownloader.Download(url = "url of post" , output="output file name here" , quality = 720)
```

quality is video quality where possible qualities are 360 , 720 , 1080

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer of redvid library.

You just need to fix your code in order to make it work properly:

```
from redvid import Downloader
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id = "a", client_secret = "b", user_agent = "c")

subreddit = reddit.subreddit("learnpython")
hot = subreddit.hot(limit=5)

downloader = Downloader(max_q=True)

for submission in hot:
    downloader.url = submission.url
    downloader.download()
```